# Clicking on image using Capybara in cucumber

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I am attempting to click an image with Capybara for a Cucumber test, but cannot find a way to get Capybara to see the image as a link.

My code for the image is:

```
link_to(image_tag('ico_edit_16.png', alt: 'Edit', class: 'icon16', title: "Edit #{qualification.title}"), edit_qualification_path(qualification))
```

Which shows up as

```
<a href="/qualifications/1/edit">
    <img class="icon16" title="Title" src="/images/ico_edit_16.png?1279303992" alt="Edit">
</a>
```

in the html, and I have been unable to find a good way to use capybara to click the image.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13):

This should work:

```
find('img.icon16').click
```

Alternatively to lookup based on the alt text:

```
find("img[alt='Edit']").click
```

Comment: It seems like that code doesn't click the link associated with the image - it may click on the image itself, but doesn't take me anywhere with the link.

I ended up passing an ID into the link behind the image, and then used click_link for that ID name, which works.

Comment: What driver are you using? It should work in Selenium, but headless drivers may not be smart enough to propagate the click up to the parent link.

Comment: remove the '@' (to make it a valid css selector)

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem when the image was not recognized because there were multiple elements hidden in the page with the same id. Try using something like this.

```
with_scope("#modal_window") do
  find("#close").click
```

Answer (score 1):

This step solves the problem for me. You have to use xpaths to match an element then find its parent. A caveat, though, is that this might not be synchronized:

When /^I follow the link containing(?:| an| a| the|) "([^\"]*)" image(?:| within "([^\"]*)")$/

```
do |*args|
  alt = args[0] ; within = args[1]

  outer = find(within)
  outer.find(:xpath, "//img[@alt='#{alt}']/..").click
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Also note, in Rails (3.1.1 in my case), for images without a given :alt value, a default alt is set by the image_tag helper:

> :alt - If no alt text is given, the file name part of the source is used (capitalized and without the extension)
>   [[From the Rails API]](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag)

So for example, for image file "kitten.jpg", you would use `find("img[@alt='Kitten']").click` (note capitalization and removal of extension).

Using this rails convention, you can search for arbitrary image links in cucumber/capybara.

Comment: ...except that every image should have meaningful alt text, so you should never need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

yeah if you are using something like in my case in haml:

```
%div{id: "23", class: 'operations'}
  %a.delete{ href: '#', class: 'smallbtn'}
    %img{ src: 'assets/delete.png', alt: 'Delete'}

 %a.edit{ href: "#", class: 'smallbtn'}
   %img{ src: 'assets/edit.png', alt: 'Editar Producto'}
```

and you don't want to use the id to click the link and you are using images, for example in my case to click on delete link you need to declare a class and later you can use the next code to click on the element and additionally to confirm a modal operation:

```
  within '#23' do
    find('.delete').click
    page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
  end
```